# Number of permutations of [2n] where $x_i + x_{i+1} \ne 2n+1$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

As stated in title, what is the number of permutations of $[2n]$ where $x_i + x_{i+1} \ne 2n+1 \;,\forall i\in[2n-1]$. 
I want to use the inclusion-exclusion theorem, and consider separately permutations with $x_i + x_{i+1} \ne 2n+1$ for a certain $i$, but the intersection of these depend on the indices and seem hard to compute.

Comment: Did you mean the number of permutations of $1, 2, 3, ...2n$?

Comment: Ah yes yes, it's just a notation...

Answer (score 0):

We have $2n-1$ conditions, but adjacent conditions can't be violated simultaneously because $x_{i-1}+x_i=2n+1=x_i+x_{i+1}$ would imply $x_{i-1}=x_{i+1}$. Thus, to choose $k$ conditions that can be violated simultaneously, we need to choose $k$ pairs of adjacent elements out of $2n$ elements, which we can do in $\binom{2n-k}k$ ways. For each such choice of $k$ conditions to violate, we can choose the numbers in the pairs in $2^k\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ ways and the remaining numbers in $(2n-2k)!$ ways. Thus the total number of admissible permutations is

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{2n-k}k2^k\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(2n-2k)!
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^n(-2)^k(2n-k)!\binom nk
\\
&=&
(2n)!\,{}_1F_1(-n;-2n;-2)\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

where the last line is due to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%28-2%29%5Ek%282n-k%29%21*binom%28n%2Ck%29+for+k%3D0..n) and $_1F_1$ is Kummer’s [confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function).